# $Cov(X_t,X_s)$ of martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals

> Let  $X_t = \int_0^t W_u^2dW_u$ martingale
>
> compute  : $$Cov(X_t,X_s)$$

note that $$Cov(\int_0^T a(t)dWt,\ \int_0^T b(t)dWt)\ = E[\int_0^T a(t)b(t)dWt]$$
My attempts:

$$Cov(X_t,X_s)\ = E[\int_0^{t\wedge s} W^{4}_udW_u]$$

**Edit**
if we use this :

$$\text{cov} \left( \int_0^T a(t) \, dW_t, \int_0^T b(t) \, dW_t \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T a(t) b(t) \, dt \right).$$

and choice $a(u) := 1_{[0,t]}(u) \cdot W_u^2,$ and $b(u) := 1_{[0,s]}(u) \cdot W_u^2,$

$T>\max\{t,s\}$

$$E[\int_{0}^T W_u^4 1_{u \leq t}1_{u\leq s}d_u] = E[\int_{0}^{s\wedge t} W_u^4 d_u]$$

In order to calculate the integral, we  use Fubini's theorem, i.e.

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^s W_u^4 \, du \right) = \int_0^{s\wedge t} \mathbb{E}(W_u^4) \, du.$$

to compute that $\mathbb{E}(W_u^4)=3u^2$ let's applying Ito's formula to $W_u^4$

$$dW_u^{4}=4W_u^{3}dW_u+\frac{1}{2}.4.3.W_u^{2}(dW_u)^2;\quad W_u^{4}(0))=0  $$
$$dW_u^{4}=4W_u^{3}dW_u+6W_u^{2}dt $$

Integrate:

$$W_u^{4}=4\int_{0}^{u}W_s^{3}dW_s+6\int_0^{u}W_s^{2}ds+0$$

$$\ldots $$

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^s W_u^4 \, du \right) = \int_0^{s\wedge t} \mathbb{E}(W_u^4) \, du.=\int_0^{s\wedge t} 3u^2 \, du=(s\wedge t)^3$$

Comment: "could we say that $\mathbb{E}(W_u^4)=0$ because $W_u$ is brownian motion" Eeeagh!? Not many are the random variables $X$ such that $\mathbb{E}(X^4)=0$...

Comment: i just want to make refresh to my memory but i think i said  something that don't have to say it !

Comment: "$W_u \sim  \ \mathcal{N}(0,u)\implies W^4_u \sim  \ \mathcal{N}(0,u^4)$" Eeeagh${}^2$!? There is something I fail to grasp, which is why so many m.se users are interested in *stochastic calculus* when they lack the basics of *probability theory*. This must have something to do with some crazy inversion in their curricula (hence, not their fault) but is not nice to see.

Comment: long time i didn't touch this field so i think  its obvious to make such mistake

Comment: Sorry, I was mainly mumbling to my own intention (as I tried to make clear).

Comment: what surprise! it's the same here

Comment: @Did Your comments are quite entertaining :) (... and I agree with you about the lack in basics of probability theory). Educ: What's $\mathbb{E}(X^4)$ if $X$ is a normal (aka Gaussian) random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^s W_u^4 \, du \right) = \int_0^{s\wedge t} \mathbb{E}(W_u^4) \, du.=\int_0^{s\wedge t} 3u^2 \, du=(s\wedge t)^3$

Comment: @Educ Yes, that's correct. Note, however, that applying Itô's formula is rather overshoot. $\mathbb{E}(X^4)$ can be easily computed for *any* Gaussian random variable $X$.

Comment: could you show me how

Comment: @Educ I suggest you open a new question and ask it there. Please add some additional information, e.g. what you know about Gaussian random variables (their density, their characteristic function,....) Alternatively, you may have a look at (almost) any book on probability theory.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, you have my respect and i love your country : Germany!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation

$$\text{cov} \left( \int_0^T a(t) \, dW_t, \int_0^T b(t) \, dW_t \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T a(t) b(t) \, dW_t \right)$$

does **not** hold. Instead it should read

$$\text{cov} \left( \int_0^T a(t) \, dW_t, \int_0^T b(t) \, dW_t \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^T a(t) b(t) \, \color{red}{dt} \right).$$

This follows from Itô's isometry and polarization.

Comment: but my question was compute this $Cov(X_t,X_s)$ known that $X_t = \int_0^t W_u^2dW_u$

Comment: @Educ I know. So how do you choose $a(t)$ and $b(t)$? (Your attempt suggests that you had some idea how to choose them...)

Comment: its just two processus, $w_u$ is brownian motion

Comment: @Educ Sure. But the point is that we would like to chosoe $a$ and $b$ in such a way that it helps us to calculate the covariation, right? We are interested in $$\text{cov} \left( \int_0^t W_u^2 \, dW_u, \int_0^s W_u^2 \, dW_u \right).$$ Any idea how to choose $a$ and $b$ so that this becomes something of the form $$\text{cov} \left( \int a(u) \, dW_u, \int b(u) \, dW_u \right)$$...?

Comment: $a=W_u-u, b=W_u-u$ am i right ?

Comment: @Educ Why do you think that this is a good choice? What has $\int (W_u-u) \, dW_u$ to do with $\int W_u^2 \, dW_u$?

Comment: i really don't know but why we don't choose $a=W_u^{2}$

Comment: @Educ Yeah, looks better, but we still have to take care of the integration limits. $\int_0^T a(u) \, dW_u$ becomes $\int_0^t W_u^2 \, dW_u$ if we choose $$a(u) := 1_{[0,t]}(u) \cdot W_u^2,$$ right? (Here $T>\max\{t,s\}$ is some fixed number.)

Comment: see my update please

Comment: @Educ Why is there no $t$ on the right-hand side?

Comment: if we assume that $s\leq t$ or we can use $s\wedge t$

Comment: @Educ Yes, but then you should mention this somewhere. So let's assume that $s \leq t$. In order to calculate the integral, use Fubini's theorem, i.e. $$\mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^s W_u^4 \, du \right) = \int_0^s \mathbb{E}(W_u^4) \, du.$$